# Retrieve rows from DB in groups according to a field using MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

imagine we have a table like :

```
item_id | item_name | item_group
--------|-----------|-----------
1       | foo       | jgKleC
2       | bar       | jgKleC
3       | hey       | jgKleC
4       | bra       | DskgvV
5       | car       | DskgvV
```

What would be a convenient way to pull this data from the database using MySQL queries in PHP to achieve this result :

```
Array (2){
  'jgKleC' = Array(3)[
    Array(3)[1, foo, jgKleC],
    Array(3)[2, bar, jgKleC],
    Array(3)[3, hey, jgKleC]
  ],
  'DskgvV' = Array(2)[
    Array(3)[4, bra, DskgvV],
    Array(3)[5, car, DskgvV]
   ]
}
```

*I'm working in PHP and using arrays only would be a plus for me.*

Answer (score 0):

```
select item_group, Concat(item_id,',',item_name,',',item_group) )  as data from tableName
```

now you get this data in $result

```
 $a='';
foreach($result as $result2){
     $a[$result2['tableName]['item_group']] =array($result2['tableName]['data'])
}
```

now may be you can get the idea

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't get me the desired structure. I edited my question, maybe it is clearer now.

Comment: run this query and try in php to get you desire out put like